# My Mac's name in terminal is off

Tags: linux, bash, macos-sierra

`apples-MacBook-Pro:Desktop Parth$` 
Why does it say apples-MacBook-Pro here? Shouldn't it say Parths-MacBook-Pro since my account name is Parth?
 
Is this correct or my system prefs are wrong? Just curious!
**Edit:**
Recently my Mac was formatted and after that the service sender guys created an account whose name was `apple` 
 I did add a new account with name Parth but still it shows `apples-MacBook-Pro`!! I checked and before the formatting it used to say `Parts-MacBook-Pro:`
[image: Please see this image to know what I mean!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is your computer/Mac hostname

You could change it by going to `System Preferences` -> `Sharing`
In the `Computer Name` settings, press the `Edit` Button

For further control that text at terminal. It is about setting the environment variable PS1

You could check your current PS1 value by running the command `echo $PS1`

Here is the reference about how and what could you set to your PS1

http://www.linuxnix.com/linuxunix-shell-ps1-prompt-explained-in-detail/